# How to set soap header in Spring Integration?

Tags: java, spring, soap, spring-integration

I want to send a soap message with Spring Integration. I use Java Config.
I've tried the flolowing interceptor, but the spring integration converts the angle brackets (<>) into html escape characters.

```
import org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceClientException;
import org.springframework.ws.client.support.interceptor.ClientInterceptor;
import org.springframework.ws.context.MessageContext;
import org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapHeader;
import org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapHeaderElement;
import org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessage;

public class MyAuthInterceptor implements ClientInterceptor {
    @Override
    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
        SoapMessage soapMessage = (SoapMessage) messageContext.getRequest();
        SoapHeader sh = soapMessage.getSoapHeader();
        QName name = new QName("http://...", "myAuth", "aut");
        sh.addHeaderElement(name).setText("<username>TestUser</username>" + "<password>TestPass</password>");
        return true;
    }
```

Here is the generated soap header:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <aut:myAuth xmlns:aut="http://.../">&lt;username&gt;TestUser&lt;/username&gt;&lt;password&gt;TestPass&lt;/password&gt;</aut:myAuth>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

Here is my configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class SpringIntegrationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public PublishSubscribeChannel inputChannel() {
        return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientInterceptor myAuthInterceptor() {
        return new MyAuthInterceptor();
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inputChannel")
    public SimpleWebServiceOutboundGateway myOutput(ClientInterceptor mekAuthInterceptor) {
        SimpleWebServiceOutboundGateway simpleWebServiceOutboundGateway = new SimpleWebServiceOutboundGateway("http://...");
        simpleWebServiceOutboundGateway.setInterceptors(myAuthInterceptor);
        return simpleWebServiceOutboundGateway;
    }
}
```

How can I set the soap header without escaping the angle brackets?

Answer (score 1):

You have to build it up using `addChildElement`s instead of setting it as text.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the tags as text which escapes the string since it is being added to an xml. Those needs to be set as elements

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPHeaderElement.html

Check the methods in the doc above and use it appropriately. Leave a comment in case you need more help.

Comment: I use Spring instead of JAVA EE. So your solution does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

@gary-russell - Your answer made sense from a logical point of view, but there are no "addChildElement" method in org.springframework.ws.soap.*. I found them in javax.xml.soap.*.

So my result looks like the following:

```
import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPException;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPHeader;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPHeaderElement;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceClientException;
import org.springframework.ws.client.support.interceptor.ClientInterceptor;
import org.springframework.ws.context.MessageContext;
import org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessage;
import org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage;

public class MySecurityInterceptor implements ClientInterceptor
{
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MySecurityInterceptor.class);

    @Override
    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException
    {
        SoapMessage soapMessage = (SoapMessage) messageContext.getRequest();

        QName securityName = new QName(
            "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd",
            "Security",
            XMLConstants.DEFAULT_NS_PREFIX);

        QName usernameToken = new QName(null, "UsernameToken", XMLConstants.DEFAULT_NS_PREFIX);

        QName username = new QName(null, "Username", XMLConstants.DEFAULT_NS_PREFIX);

        QName password = new QName(null, "Password", XMLConstants.DEFAULT_NS_PREFIX);

        try
        {
            SOAPMessage mySoapMessage = ((SaajSoapMessage) soapMessage).getSaajMessage();

            SOAPHeader header = mySoapMessage.getSOAPHeader();

            SOAPHeaderElement securityElement = header.addHeaderElement(securityName);

            SOAPElement usernameTokenElement = securityElement.addChildElement(usernameToken);

            SOAPElement usernameElement = usernameTokenElement.addChildElement(username);

            SOAPElement passwordElement = usernameTokenElement.addChildElement(password);

            usernameElement.setTextContent("jxep-Zenmonics-1-i101@jxtest.local");
            passwordElement.setTextContent("3Sg%T~1q4z!QnH6#+5pD");
        }
        catch (SOAPException e)
        {
            log.error("Error!", e);
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException
    {
        // Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException
    {
        // Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(MessageContext messageContext, Exception ex) throws WebServiceClientException
    {
        // Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```